# How to display an HTML page with the ColorBox jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

How do I display an HTML page with [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)?

Comment: Be specific. What exactly are you looking for.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open an outside HTML here is the sample

[**http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html**](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html)

Code would be something like

***HTML***

```
<a class='example5' href="yourpage.html" title="My Page">Outside HTML (Ajax)</a>
```

***jQuery***

```
$(".example5").colorbox();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just refer the jQuery plugin in your HTML page using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path of jQuery library"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path of color box"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
<a class="example5 cboxElement" href="../content/ajax.html" title="Homer Defined">
    Outside HTML (Ajax)
</a>
```

js:

```
$(".example5").colorbox();
```

just look at their [example page](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html)